# remote: ! Precompiling assets failed. remote: ! remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I tried to push a rails app onto Heroku. It keeps failing to precompile. My prompts are posted below. I've searched this site and one of the most common piece of advice is to add

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to your application.rb. This did not work. I saw git telling me "remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install" so I downloaded and installed Yarn. However, git still acts like nothing happened because when I put git push Heroku master it gives me the exact same thing. Please let me know if there's a way to get around this. If you need more details then I will be happy to post them. Thanks!

```
Enumerating objects: 203, done.
Counting objects: 100% (203/203), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (184/184), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 1.87 MiB | 1.62 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 65), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Resolving dependencies...
remote:        Fetching rake 12.3.2
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Installing rake 12.3.2
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Installing erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.4
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching rack 2.0.6
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.6
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Fetching arel 9.0.0
remote:        Installing arel 9.0.0
remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.2.4
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.2.4 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Fetching thor 0.20.3
remote:        Installing thor 0.20.3
remote:        Fetching duktape 2.0.1.0
remote:        Installing duktape 2.0.1.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Fetching pg 1.1.3
remote:        Installing pg 1.1.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching puma 3.12.0
remote:        Installing puma 3.12.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.9.0
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.9.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.2.0
remote:        Installing i18n 1.2.0
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Installing marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Installing uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.3.2
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.3.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Installing loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Fetching activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching sass 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching railties 5.2.2
remote:        Installing railties 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Fetching rails 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Installing rails 5.2.2
remote:        Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from i18n:
remote:
remote:        HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
remote:        But that may break your application.
remote:
remote:        Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
remote:        If you're using I18n 1.1.x and Rails (< 6.0), this should be
remote:        'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
remote:        If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.
remote:
remote:        For more info see:
remote:        https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
remote:
remote:        Post-install message from sass:
remote:
remote:        Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.
remote:
remote:        * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
remote:          primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
remote:
remote:        * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
remote:          sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
remote:
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811
remote:
remote:        Bundle completed (66.42s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.0.pre.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2018-12-18T00:20:36.942680 #1410]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/public/assets/background-22f0da6b56b83c5381a219c64b68ace6f415ead2fa430af99a9805cf48660ca7.jpg
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: operator (=). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_91a0385c01ee50024d705167797cefde/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to secure-earth-41846.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/secure-earth-41846.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secure-earth-41846.git'
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yarn comment in the output is probably a red herring. `Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: operator (=). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).` looks like a potential culprit.

You can try overriding uglifier in your `config/environmonts/production.rb` file per this [uglifier post](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/127#issuecomment-352224986)

Replace

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

with

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

It looks like you were missing a js/v8 engine. Adding `gem 'mini_racer'` in his `Gemfile` in the production block resolved the issue. It was added to the production block because mini_racer isn't available locally

Comment: When I get rid of that line entirely it successfully deploys but when I visit the URL it's on I get this page on my web browser: "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Comment: @Alex can you post your Gemfile? I want to make sure you've got uglifier in there (sounds like you do) and mini_racer or another JavaScript interpreter (therubyracer is also popular)

Comment: @Alex add `gem 'mini_racer'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` to update your `Gemfile.lock`, then commit & push to heroku again

Comment: Installing libv8 6.7.288.46.1 with native extensions
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink -
(vendor/depot_tools/support/chromite_wrapper,
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-6.7.288.46.1/vendor/depot_tools/cbuildbot)
An error occurred while installing libv8 (6.7.288.46.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '6.7.288.46.1' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.2.4, which depends on
    libv8

Comment: I hit enter and it just sent that comment. That is the error message I get after running bundle install.

Comment: @Alex try adding that to your `production` group only, maybe? therubyracer doesn't work on windows and I'm not sure mini_racer does either. If that doesn't work, just commit it and push it up without the bundle install. (I think heroku will need to rebundle the gems anyways)

Comment: If you meant putting in the gemfile as group :production do gem 'mini_racer' end that's what I did and it failed to deploy. I am unable to push it to Heroku at all now.

Comment: I just ran $ heroku run rake db:migrate
and it deployed! Although without my formatting. But that is another question for another topic.